# AFNetworking + UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, flickr

I'm working on UICollectionView that load images from Flickr. When i'm reload data the uicollectionview, the app goes force close and show me error:

```
malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=3956588544) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I was trying to get total images that returned by Flickr API using AFNetworking, here's the code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest"
      parameters:@{@"method":@"flickr.people.getPublicPhotos",
                   @"api_key":flickrApiKey,
                   @"user_id":flickrUserId,
                   @"format":@"json",
                   @"nojsoncallback":@"1"}
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        flickrPhotos = [responseObject objectForKey:@"photos"];

        NSLog(@"total : %@",[flickrPhotos objectForKey:@"total"]);
        [self.animationCollectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```

How I to get total images and reload the uicollectionview content based on return from Flickr API?

Comment: Is this the same code you are using to load the images the first time? Does it work the first time or not at all?

Comment: Hi @MikeTaverne, i'm loading images for the first time using NSArray to test the uicollectionview

Comment: post your collectionview datasource implementation?  where you have implemented AFHTTPRequestOperationManager code, in viewdidload or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without seeing all your code. I'd make sure your code follows the same approach as in this [tutorial](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/). It will show you how to set up a `UICollectionView` with an array of items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your code and I can't see where you're storing your retrieved pictures.

The line `flickrPhotos = [responseObject objectForKey:@"photos"];` assigns the objects to local variable which is gone when the execution goes out of the block. Maybe you should be assigning `responseObject[@"photos"]` to `self.flickrPhotos`?

Answer (score 0):

JSON from `flickr.people.getPublicPhotos` looks like this

```
{ "photos": { "page": 1, "pages": 1, "perpage": 100, "total": 4, 
    "photo": [
      { "id": "2084538116", "owner": "21371325@N02", "secret": "7876c3e2a4", "server": "2034", "farm": 3, "title": "Jace & denise", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
      { "id": "2084538068", "owner": "21371325@N02", "secret": "e0a89002c0", "server": "2274", "farm": 3, "title": "jace", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
      { "id": "2083753601", "owner": "21371325@N02", "secret": "a1f0b4b6ff", "server": "2180", "farm": 3, "title": "Boulder city hall", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 },
      { "id": "2084537976", "owner": "21371325@N02", "secret": "73ec0231a5", "server": "2039", "farm": 3, "title": "Reindogs", "ispublic": 1, "isfriend": 0, "isfamily": 0 }
    ] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

that you need try it:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest"
      parameters:@{@"method":@"flickr.people.getPublicPhotos",
                   @"api_key":flickrApiKey,
                   @"user_id":flickrUserId,
                   @"format":@"json",
                   @"nojsoncallback":@"1"}
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        CGFloat total = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"photos.total"] floatValue];
        flickrPhotos = [responseObject objectForKey:@"photos.photo"];

        NSLog(@"total : %f", total);
        [self.animationCollectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];
```